# Building an NER model and getting the following: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, named-entity-recognition

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.dominodatalab.com/blog/named-entity-recognition-ner-challenges-and-model) to build a NER model for practice in Machine Learning.

However, when towards the end of the tutorial when I run the code, I am triggering an
"AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'
that occurs because of line 174:

```
history = ner_model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS, validation_split=0.1, verbose=2)
```

If anyone can help me solve this issue as I am a beginner in Machine Learning as well as Python Coding, that would very much be appreciated.

I am using Keras 2.9.0, Tensorflow 3.2.0, and Pip 22.2.2

The rest of my code is the same as in the link provided to the tutorial above! Hope someone can help me, thank you.

Comment: I think you have an error in your Tensorflow version.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version problem. In the tutorial you linked is shown the import: `from keras_contrib.layers import CRF`.
However `keras_contrib` is not available for tensorflow version >=2.0. It has been migrated to `tensorflow_addons`.

You should consider whether it is best for you to switch your tensorflow version to 1.x, or try to migrate from `keras_contrib` to `tensorflow_addons`. Here is the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/CRF) of the migrated CRF layer. Personally I would prefer this second option.